# :normal o in visual mode WORKS

Tags: visual-mode, command

In my environment, invoking :normal in visual mode does visual mode command.

```
" A map for calling command without quitting visual mode
" It gets the cursor to the other side of selection
vnoremap s <Cmd>normal o<CR>
```

I think this is a helpful feature if this is officially intended, but I'm afraid it's not and my plugins using this behavior doesn't work in other environments because `:h :normal` says

> Executes Normal mode commands

Is it properly working when :normal does visual mode command, and is that common to all environments?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, "normal" executes a sequence of keys. The point is that "cmd" (unlike "colon") suppresses mode switching and so it starts executing the sequence while still in Visual mode.

But you don't need "normal" here at all. To access Visual mode keys simply map to these keys directly; also, use "esc" and "gv" to return to Normal and to restart Visual respectively.